# Way to show full date instead of just hh:ss in LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

[image]

The above screenshot shows the zoomed out version where date is shownig full format but on zooming in it just shows time in hh:ss. 
The second screenshot shows the zoomed in version
[image]
Is there any way to show full date on legend in Zoomed In version ? Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update for LightningChart JS v3.4.0

LightningChart JS v3.4.0 has more options available for [`DateTimeTickStrategy`](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/datetimetickstrategy.html) axis formatting. It's now possible to set different formatting for each "level" of ticks.

```js
const formatting = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}

chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, (styler)=>
    styler.setDateOrigin(dateOrigin)
        .setFormattingDay(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingDecade(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingHour(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMilliSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMinute(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMonth(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingWeek(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingYear(formatting, formatting, formatting)
)
```

[image: LightningChart JS DateTime axis with custom formatting]

---

### Old LightningChart JS v1.3.1 answer

When the [DateTime](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/globals.html#axistickstrategies.datetime) AxisTickStrategy is created, you can supply it formatting options through the third parameter in the `AxisTickStrategies.DateTime()` call. This third parameter expects a [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) options object to be provided to it.

Following the documentation of `Intl.DateTimeFormat.options` object properties. We can get the date and time to be always visible with

```js
lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.DateTime(
        undefined, 
        undefined,
        {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            day: 'numeric',
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric'
        }
    )
})
```

You can pass `undefined` to the first and second parameter if you want to use the default values for those.

With that we can get a result that looks like the following screenshot: [image: LightningChart JS DateTime axis with custom formatting]

When doing it this way the formatting will not change when zooming in, it will always stay the same. The formatting can be customized more by following the `Intl.DateTimeFormat.options` properties documentation.