# How to show custom label in line chart or scatter chart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am adding data to charts like this

```
const data = [
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:22", "173.9"],
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:40", "175.3"],
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:58", "172.4"]
]

function stringToDate(s)  {
  s = s.split(/[-: ]/);
  return new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
}

for(var key in data)
{
    var xTime = stringToDate(data[key][0]);
    var yVal  =  parseFloat(data[key][1]);
    series.add({ x: xTime.getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime(), y: yVal})
}
```

How do  I show custom label to it, For example I want to show full date for above line series and also for other scatter charts , I want to show custom label like below.

```
series.add({ x: xTime.getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime(), y: yVal , label : "my own text" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a full date for a series using a DateTime axis you can take a look at my previously posted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839354/6198227 The sort version of it is to define a format options based on [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) when defining the axis tick strategy for a axis.

Custom labels can be done by creating [custom ticks](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/axis.html#addcustomtick). The text inside the tick can be defined with a text formatter set by [`Axis.setTextFormatter`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/customtick.html#settextformatter). The formatter function gets the position and the tick itself as parameters so those can be used to define the text inside the tick if that's needed.

```js
const tick = lineSeries.axisX.addCustomTick()
    .setGridStrokeLength(0)
    .setTextFormatter(()=>'My Text')
    .setValue(dataFrequency * 50)
```

See below snippet for a implementation of both custom DateTime formatting and the use of custom ticks. The snippet is based on [DateTime Axis example](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0020-dateTimeAxis.html) from the LightningChart JS Interactive Examples.

LightningChart JS v1.3.1 example:

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    DataPatterns,
    emptyFill,
    emptyLine
} = lcjs

// Create a XY Chart.
const dateOrigin = new Date(2008, 0, 1)
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.DateTime(
        dateOrigin, 
        undefined,
        {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            day: 'numeric',
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric'
        }
    )
})
    .setTitle('Customer Satisfaction')

chart.setPadding({ right: '5' })

// Add a progressive line series.
// Using the DataPatterns object to select the horizontalProgressive pattern for the line series.
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive })
    .setName('Customer Satisfaction')

// Generate some points using for each month
const dataFrequency = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

// Setup view nicely.
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setScrollStrategy(undefined)
    .setInterval(0, 100)
    .setTitle('Satisfaction %')

// Data for the plotting
const satisfactionData = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 8 },
    { x: 2, y: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 18 },
    { x: 4, y: 22 },
    { x: 5, y: 32 },
    { x: 6, y: 40 },
    { x: 7, y: 48 },
    { x: 8, y: 50 },
    { x: 9, y: 54 },
    { x: 10, y: 59 },
    { x: 11, y: 65 },
    { x: 12, y: 70 },
    { x: 13, y: 68 },
    { x: 14, y: 70 },
    { x: 15, y: 69 },
    { x: 16, y: 66 },
    { x: 17, y: 65.4 },
    { x: 18, y: 64 },
    { x: 19, y: 65 },
    { x: 20, y: 63.5 },
    { x: 21, y: 62 },
    { x: 22, y: 61.2 },
    { x: 23, y: 63 },
    { x: 24, y: 61 },
    { x: 25, y: 62 },
    { x: 26, y: 62 },
    { x: 27, y: 60 },
    { x: 28, y: 57.8 },
    { x: 29, y: 58 },
    { x: 30, y: 61 },
    { x: 31, y: 59 },
    { x: 32, y: 63 },
    { x: 33, y: 61 },
    { x: 34, y: 61.8 },
    { x: 35, y: 62 },
    { x: 36, y: 59.9 },
    { x: 37, y: 58 },
    { x: 38, y: 60 },
    { x: 39, y: 63 },
    { x: 40, y: 59.5 },
    { x: 41, y: 62.5 },
    { x: 42, y: 59.7 },
    { x: 43, y: 57 },
    { x: 44, y: 61 },
    { x: 45, y: 59 },
    { x: 46, y: 61 },
    { x: 47, y: 65 },
    { x: 48, y: 62 },
    { x: 49, y: 60 },
    { x: 50, y: 58 },
    { x: 51, y: 59 },
    { x: 52, y: 61 },
    { x: 53, y: 64 },
    { x: 54, y: 65.5 },
    { x: 55, y: 67 },
    { x: 56, y: 68 },
    { x: 57, y: 69 },
    { x: 58, y: 68 },
    { x: 59, y: 69.5 },
    { x: 60, y: 69.9 },
    { x: 61, y: 68.5 },
    { x: 62, y: 67 },
    { x: 63, y: 65 },
    { x: 64, y: 63 },
    { x: 65, y: 60 },
    { x: 66, y: 61.6 },
    { x: 67, y: 62 },
    { x: 68, y: 61 },
    { x: 69, y: 60 },
    { x: 70, y: 63.3 },
    { x: 71, y: 62.7 },
    { x: 72, y: 64.3 },
    { x: 73, y: 63 },
    { x: 74, y: 61.2 },
    { x: 75, y: 60 },
    { x: 76, y: 61 },
    { x: 77, y: 64 },
    { x: 78, y: 61.9 },
    { x: 79, y: 61 },
    { x: 80, y: 58 },
    { x: 81, y: 59 },
    { x: 82, y: 60.5 },
    { x: 83, y: 61 },
    { x: 84, y: 63 },
    { x: 85, y: 64.5 },
    { x: 86, y: 65 },
    { x: 87, y: 66.2 },
    { x: 88, y: 64.9 },
    { x: 89, y: 63 },
    { x: 90, y: 62 },
    { x: 91, y: 63 },
    { x: 92, y: 61.8 },
    { x: 93, y: 62 },
    { x: 94, y: 63 },
    { x: 95, y: 64.2 },
    { x: 96, y: 63 },
    { x: 97, y: 61 },
    { x: 98, y: 59.7 },
    { x: 99, y: 61 },
    { x: 100, y: 58 },
    { x: 101, y: 59 },
    { x: 102, y: 58 },
    { x: 103, y: 58 },
    { x: 104, y: 57.5 },
    { x: 105, y: 59.2 },
    { x: 106, y: 60 },
    { x: 107, y: 61.9 },
    { x: 108, y: 63 },
    { x: 109, y: 64.1 },
    { x: 110, y: 65.9 },
    { x: 111, y: 64 },
    { x: 112, y: 65 },
    { x: 113, y: 62 },
    { x: 114, y: 60 },
    { x: 115, y: 58 },
    { x: 116, y: 57 },
    { x: 117, y: 58.2 },
    { x: 118, y: 58.6 },
    { x: 119, y: 59.3 },
    { x: 120, y: 61 }
]

// Adding points to the series
lineSeries.add(satisfactionData.map((point) => ({ x: point.x * dataFrequency, y: point.y })))

// Show the customized result table for each point
lineSeries.setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
    return builder
        .addRow('Customer Satisfaction')
        .addRow(series.axisX.formatValue(xValue))
        .addRow(yValue.toFixed(2) + "%")
})

const tick = lineSeries.axisX.addCustomTick()
    .setGridStrokeLength(0)
    .setTextFormatter(()=>'My Text')
    .setValue(dataFrequency * 50)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.2.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

### Update for LightningChart JS v3.4.0

DateTime axis formatting options have changed a little bit, there are more options to format based on the zoom level. And `setResultTableFormatter` has been renamed to `setCursorResultTableFormatter`.

```js
const formatting = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'}

chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, (styler)=>
    styler.setDateOrigin(dateOrigin)
        .setFormattingDay(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingDecade(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingHour(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMilliSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMinute(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingMonth(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingWeek(formatting, formatting, formatting)
        .setFormattingYear(formatting, formatting, formatting)
)
```

LightningChart JS v3.4.0 example:

```js
// Import LightningChartJS
const {
  lightningChart,
  AxisTickStrategies,
  DataPatterns,
  emptyFill,
  emptyLine
} = lcjs

// Create a XY Chart.
const dateOrigin = new Date(2008, 0, 1)
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
  .setTitle('Customer Satisfaction')

const formatting = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric'
}

chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, (styler) =>
  styler.setDateOrigin(dateOrigin)
  .setFormattingDay(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingDecade(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingHour(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingMilliSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingMinute(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingMonth(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingSecond(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingWeek(formatting, formatting, formatting)
  .setFormattingYear(formatting, formatting, formatting)
)

chart.setPadding({
  right: '5'
})

// Add a progressive line series.
// Using the DataPatterns object to select the horizontalProgressive pattern for the line series.
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
    dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive
  })
  .setName('Customer Satisfaction')

// Generate some points using for each month
const dataFrequency = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

// Setup view nicely.
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  .setScrollStrategy(undefined)
  .setInterval(0, 100)
  .setTitle('Satisfaction %')

// Data for the plotting
const satisfactionData = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 8 },
    { x: 2, y: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 18 },
    { x: 4, y: 22 },
    { x: 5, y: 32 },
    { x: 6, y: 40 },
    { x: 7, y: 48 },
    { x: 8, y: 50 },
    { x: 9, y: 54 },
    { x: 10, y: 59 },
    { x: 11, y: 65 },
    { x: 12, y: 70 },
    { x: 13, y: 68 },
    { x: 14, y: 70 },
    { x: 15, y: 69 },
    { x: 16, y: 66 },
    { x: 17, y: 65.4 },
    { x: 18, y: 64 },
    { x: 19, y: 65 },
    { x: 20, y: 63.5 },
    { x: 21, y: 62 },
    { x: 22, y: 61.2 },
    { x: 23, y: 63 },
    { x: 24, y: 61 },
    { x: 25, y: 62 },
    { x: 26, y: 62 },
    { x: 27, y: 60 },
    { x: 28, y: 57.8 },
    { x: 29, y: 58 },
    { x: 30, y: 61 },
    { x: 31, y: 59 },
    { x: 32, y: 63 },
    { x: 33, y: 61 },
    { x: 34, y: 61.8 },
    { x: 35, y: 62 },
    { x: 36, y: 59.9 },
    { x: 37, y: 58 },
    { x: 38, y: 60 },
    { x: 39, y: 63 },
    { x: 40, y: 59.5 },
    { x: 41, y: 62.5 },
    { x: 42, y: 59.7 },
    { x: 43, y: 57 },
    { x: 44, y: 61 },
    { x: 45, y: 59 },
    { x: 46, y: 61 },
    { x: 47, y: 65 },
    { x: 48, y: 62 },
    { x: 49, y: 60 },
    { x: 50, y: 58 },
    { x: 51, y: 59 },
    { x: 52, y: 61 },
    { x: 53, y: 64 },
    { x: 54, y: 65.5 },
    { x: 55, y: 67 },
    { x: 56, y: 68 },
    { x: 57, y: 69 },
    { x: 58, y: 68 },
    { x: 59, y: 69.5 },
    { x: 60, y: 69.9 },
    { x: 61, y: 68.5 },
    { x: 62, y: 67 },
    { x: 63, y: 65 },
    { x: 64, y: 63 },
    { x: 65, y: 60 },
    { x: 66, y: 61.6 },
    { x: 67, y: 62 },
    { x: 68, y: 61 },
    { x: 69, y: 60 },
    { x: 70, y: 63.3 },
    { x: 71, y: 62.7 },
    { x: 72, y: 64.3 },
    { x: 73, y: 63 },
    { x: 74, y: 61.2 },
    { x: 75, y: 60 },
    { x: 76, y: 61 },
    { x: 77, y: 64 },
    { x: 78, y: 61.9 },
    { x: 79, y: 61 },
    { x: 80, y: 58 },
    { x: 81, y: 59 },
    { x: 82, y: 60.5 },
    { x: 83, y: 61 },
    { x: 84, y: 63 },
    { x: 85, y: 64.5 },
    { x: 86, y: 65 },
    { x: 87, y: 66.2 },
    { x: 88, y: 64.9 },
    { x: 89, y: 63 },
    { x: 90, y: 62 },
    { x: 91, y: 63 },
    { x: 92, y: 61.8 },
    { x: 93, y: 62 },
    { x: 94, y: 63 },
    { x: 95, y: 64.2 },
    { x: 96, y: 63 },
    { x: 97, y: 61 },
    { x: 98, y: 59.7 },
    { x: 99, y: 61 },
    { x: 100, y: 58 },
    { x: 101, y: 59 },
    { x: 102, y: 58 },
    { x: 103, y: 58 },
    { x: 104, y: 57.5 },
    { x: 105, y: 59.2 },
    { x: 106, y: 60 },
    { x: 107, y: 61.9 },
    { x: 108, y: 63 },
    { x: 109, y: 64.1 },
    { x: 110, y: 65.9 },
    { x: 111, y: 64 },
    { x: 112, y: 65 },
    { x: 113, y: 62 },
    { x: 114, y: 60 },
    { x: 115, y: 58 },
    { x: 116, y: 57 },
    { x: 117, y: 58.2 },
    { x: 118, y: 58.6 },
    { x: 119, y: 59.3 },
    { x: 120, y: 61 }
]

// Adding points to the series
lineSeries.add(satisfactionData.map((point) => ({
  x: point.x * dataFrequency,
  y: point.y
})))

// Show the customized result table for each point
lineSeries.setCursorResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
  return builder
    .addRow('Customer Satisfaction')
    .addRow(series.axisX.formatValue(xValue))
    .addRow(yValue.toFixed(2) + "%")
})

const tick = lineSeries.axisX.addCustomTick()
  .setGridStrokeLength(0)
  .setTextFormatter(() => 'My Text')
  .setValue(dataFrequency * 50)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.4.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: No longer valid as of latest versions

Comment: Added update for LightningChart JS v3.4.0

Comment: That was quick! Thank you :)

Comment: Might be worth it to update the DateTimeTickStrategy doc because it's not obvious that it's possible to set more than one formatting scope (as in your great example)